# User data in evince and cups

Tags: cups, troubleshooting, evince

Some days ago my evince stopped printing. After reinstalling it and trying different versions without success I figured out that it works from other user accounts on the same box.

So which files stores evince and cups per user basis such that I can remove or modify some files for the user where evince makes problems?

**Edit #1**

Printing from all other applications works. Evince from the particular user account just feeds out empty pages.

**Edit #2**

The user accounts where it worked didn't have any `./config/evince/` and `./cups`. I just deleted those directories in the account where it doesn't work, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas what may be different between the users regarding evince printing?

Comment: Can you print this particular PDF file from something other than evince? I'd try xpdf for example. Trying to narrow down the issue further. Also what version of evince are you using? Found this bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/850195

Comment: There is also this bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/186655

Comment: Found this issue being referenced on askubuntu as well, http://askubuntu.com/questions/265097/how-to-get-12-10-fix-for-pdf-printing-problem-where-some-pages-print-blank-in. Given this was working for you and now not, did you happen to apply some updates to your system recently?

Comment: @don_crissti Yes it happens with all pdf I tried. Print preview works. If I start evince from terminal and print a pdf I don't get any output in the terminal.

Comment: Can you try the steps in section #3 of my answer and let us know if they fixed your issue?

Comment: Thanks, removing `$HOME/.gnome2/evince` solved the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say in your question but are you able to print using other applications? The command line? I'd confirm that you're printer is still configured and working correctly by doing the following:

#### 1. confirm that printer is setup and accessible using:

#### `lpq`

```
# check for jobs on the default printer
% lpq
mfc-8480dn is ready
no entries

# check for any jobs on all printers
% lpq -a
no entries
```

#### `lpinfo -v`

```
% sudo lpinfo -v
network beh
direct scsi
network socket
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network http
network ipp
network https
network lpd
network dnssd://Canon%20S820%20%40%20scully._ipp._tcp.local/cups
direct hp
network smb
direct hpfax
network lpd://mfc-8480dn.bubba.net/BINARY_P1
%
```

#### test print from command-line

```
lpr somefile.txt
```

#### Try using the Troubleshooting Wizard

> There is a troubleshooting wizard in system-config-printer (System ->
>   Administration -> Printing in GNOME classic, Gear icon at the upper
>   right of the screen -> Printers in Unity). You find it in the "Help"
>   menu of system-config-printer. It produces a text file with a lot of
>   useful information to attach to bug reports. Follow the instructions
>   of the wizard. If you reach the test page step, you can either click
>   the button to print the test page or you can print a job to the
>   selected printer from any application or from the command line. The
>   job will be shown in the integrated job viewer. Wait until it
>   completes or goes into "Stopped" state. ONLY THEN AND NOT BEFORE mark
>   the checkbox at the job, answer whether the job got printed correctly,
>   and click "Forward". After that the file will get generated. Save it
>   and attach it to your bug report.

[image: ss of printer troubleshooting]

Further details are available in the [Ubuntu Debugging Printing Problems Wiki Topic](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems).

#### 2. Issues with Ubuntu and Evince printing blank pages

During researching this issue I did come across a lot of people having issues with printing and blank pages on various versions of Ubuntu.

- [Document Viewer 2.32.0 (Evince) prints a blank page - bugid#: 186655](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/186655)
- [Some pages appear blank when printing/previewing PDFs - bugid#: 186655](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/850195)
- [How to get 12.10 fix for PDF Printing Problem (where some pages print blank) in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265097/how-to-get-12-10-fix-for-pdf-printing-problem-where-some-pages-print-blank-in)

There was a somewhat involved fix that I found here, [Fixing PDF printing problems on Ubuntu 12.04](http://unquietwiki.blogspot.com/2012/05/fixing-pdf-printing-problems-on-ubuntu.html). In the comments the fix mentioned fixed the issue for some but not all of the commenters.

#### 3. The directory: $HOME/.gnome2/evince

You might try either deleting the `print-settings` file under `$HOME/.gnome2/evince` or even just deleting that directory entirely.

```
$ rm -fr $HOME/.gnome2/evince
```

Comment: The OP wrote 'Printing from all other applications works. Evince from the particular user account just feeds out empty pages.', so it looks like he has not problem with reaching the printer.

Comment: @Anthon, thanks I saw he edited his question.

Comment: @student - see my updates, section #3 in my answer.

Comment: AWESOME! That was an annoying issue, glad we figured it out! Can you please mark my answer as accepted so that other ppl know it's been resolved? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should compare the following file between your account and an account for which printing works:

```
~/.config/evince/print-settings
```

(and/or backup your copy and replace with one from another user). If that doesn't help you might try to replace the whole ~/.config/evince directory.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I realised that was `evince` only. The cups options are in `~/.cups/lptoptions` can you compare those as well?